# No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, ffmpeg

I am a novice at ffmpeg and have recently taken over a code base built by a previous engineer. The FFmpeg code is on an app engine that will edit the videos when they are uploaded.

This code generated a title animation that will later be used as an overlay.

```
exports.generateTitleAnimation = function(metadata, destPath, options = {}) {
const peeqLogoPath = "/app/assets/peeq-logo.png";
const whiteBarMovPath = "/app/assets/whiteBar.mov";
const titleFontPath = "/app/assets/Sofia-Pro-Black.otf";
const dateStrFontPath = "/app/assets/Sofia-Pro-Medium.otf";
const outputDuration = 5.52;
const src01 = "color=c=white:s=1920x1080:duration=" + outputDuration;
const src02 = "color=c=white@0.0:s=1920x1080:r=120:duration=" + outputDuration;

var dateStrXOffset = "(92";
var filterComplexStr = "[1]";

if (metadata.title) {
    const title = metadata.title.toUpperCase();
    filterComplexStr += "drawtext=fontfile=" + titleFontPath + ":text='" + title + "':x='floor(92*(min((t-1.75)^29,0)+max((t-3.75)^29,0)+1))':y=622+30+2:fontsize=70:fontcolor=black:ft_load_flags=render,";
}
if (metadata.subTitle) {
    const subTitle = metadata.subTitle.toUpperCase();
    filterComplexStr += "drawtext=fontfile=" + titleFontPath + ":text='" + subTitle + "':x='floor(92*(min((t-2.0)^29,0.0)+max((t-3.8)^29,0.0)+1.0))':y=622+184-20-60+9:fontsize=46:fontcolor=black:ft_load_flags=render,";

    dateStrXOffset += "+30*" + (subTitle.length + 1);
}
if (metadata.dateStr) {
    filterComplexStr += "drawtext=fontfile=" + dateStrFontPath + ":text='" + metadata.dateStr + "':x='floor(" + dateStrXOffset + ")*(min((t-2.0)^29,0.0)+max((t-3.8)^29,0.0)+1.0))':y=622+184-20-60+9:fontsize=46:fontcolor=black:ft_load_flags=render,";
}
console.log("generateTitleAnimation generating")
filterComplexStr += "split=10[t01][t02][t03][t04][t05][t06][t07][t08][t09][t10];[t02]setpts=PTS+0.0166/TB[d02];[t03]setpts=PTS+0.033/TB[d03];[t04]setpts=PTS+0.05/TB[d04];[t05]setpts=PTS+0.0666/TB[d05];[t06]setpts=PTS+0.083/TB[d06];[t07]setpts=PTS+0.1/TB[d07];[t08]setpts=PTS+0.1166/TB[d08];[t09]setpts=PTS+0.133/TB[d09];[t10]setpts=PTS+0.15/TB[d10];[d10][d09]blend=average,[d08]blend=darken,[d07]blend=average,[d06]blend=darken,[d05]blend=average,[d04]blend=darken,[d03]blend= average,[d02]blend=darken,[t01]blend=average,colorkey=white:0.2:0.0,perspective=y1=W*0.176327:y3=H+W*0.176327[text01];[2][3]overlay=x=(W-w)*0.5:y=(H-h)*0.5:enable='between(t,0,3.0)'[logo01];[logo01][text01]overlay[outv]";

var args = ["-y", "-f", "lavfi", "-i", src01, "-f", "lavfi", "-i", src02, "-i", whiteBarMovPath, "-i", peeqLogoPath, "-filter_complex", filterComplexStr, "-vcodec", "qtrle", "-crf:v", "28", "-codec:a", "aac", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "44100", "-ab", "128k", "-map", "[outv]", destPath];

//console.log("args", args);
return childProcess.spawn('ffmpeg', args).then((ffResult) => {
    return destPath;
}, (err) => {
    //console.error(new Error("generateTitleAnimation:" + err));
    console.error(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
});};
```

destPath is a .mov file

Up till a few days ago, the backend started throwing up this error

```
stderr: 'ffmpeg version 3.4.2-1~16.04.york0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018
 the FFmpeg developers\n built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-
6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 20160609\n configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-
version=\'1~16.04.york0.2\' --toolchain=hardened --
libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --
enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --
enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --
enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --
enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-
libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-
libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --
enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-
libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-
libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --
enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 -
-enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-
openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --
enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-
libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared\n libavutil 55. 78.100 / 55.
 78.100\n libavcodec 57.107.100 / 57.107.100\n libavformat 57. 83.100 /
 57. 83.100\n libavdevice 57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100\n libavfilter 
6.107.100 / 6.107.100\n libavresample 3. 7. 0 / 3. 7. 0\n libswscale 4.
 8.100 / 4. 8.100\n libswresample 2. 9.100 / 2. 9.100\n libpostproc 54.
 7.100 / 54. 7.100\nInput #0, lavfi, from 
\'color=c=white:s=1920x1080:duration=5.52\':\n Duration: N/A, start: 
0.000000, bitrate: N/A\n Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 
0x30323449), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25
 tbc\nInput #1, lavfi, from 
\'color=c=white@0.0:s=1920x1080:r=120:duration=5.52\':\n Duration: N/A,
 start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A\n Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 /
 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 120 fps, 120 tbr,
 120 tbn, 120 tbc\nInput #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 
\'/app/assets/whiteBar.mov\':\n Metadata:\n major_brand : qt \n 
minor_version : 537199360\n compatible_brands: qt \n creation_time : 
2018-04-27T15:55:18.000000Z\n Duration: 00:00:05.52, start: 0.000000, 
bitrate: 54847 kb/s\n Stream #2:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle / 
0x20656C72), bgra(progressive), 1920x1080, 53326 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 60 
fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)\n Metadata:\n creation_time : 
2018-04-27T15:55:18.000000Z\n handler_name : Apple Alias Data Handler\n
 encoder : Animation\n timecode : 00:00:00:00\n Stream #2:1(eng): Data:
 none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)\n Metadata:\n creation_time
 : 2018-04-27T15:55:18.000000Z\n handler_name : Apple Alias Data
 Handler\n timecode : 00:00:00:00\nInput #3, png_pipe, from 
\'/app/assets/peeq-logo.png\':\n Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A\n Stream 
#3:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 452x207 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 452:207], 25 
tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc\nCodec AVOption crf (Select the quality for 
constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (/tmp/972967.mov) 
has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either 
wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a 
private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any 
stream.\nCodec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for 
output file #0 (/tmp/972967.mov) has not been used for any stream. The 
most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no 
video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was 
not actually used for any stream.\nStream mapping:\n Stream #1:0 
(rawvideo) -> drawtext\n Stream #2:0 (qtrle) -> overlay:main\n Stream 
#3:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay\n overlay -> Stream #0:0 (qtrle)\nPress 
[q] to stop, [?] for help\n[swscaler @ 0x56080b828180] No accelerated 
colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.\n[swscaler @ 
0x56080b8b5f40] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuva420p to argb.\n',
```

However, this error only occurs on the app engine. Running nom test on my Mac generates the title perfectly.

Comment: Lazyman guess is to [update](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) your ancient `ffmpeg` (I didn't try to duplicate the issue).

Comment: *No accelerated 
colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb* is a warning, not an error. All it means is that the code for this conversion is generic C rather than ASM using a dedicated instruction set  By itself, it won't prevent the video from being processed, it'll be slower. By how much, depends on resolution.

Comment: so @gyan , ah, that is key information.  I've been knocking myself out, assuming that the process failed at *No accelerated colorspace conversion found...*.   I wonder if you could tell me, is there somewhere in the ... manual ?! ... that explains the warning, what you just said.  Where would I look in the ffmpeg doco for such a thing?  I'm using ffmpeg, compiled in to iOS, as a curiosity.

Comment: `-vf super2xsai,scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2` worked for me when I ran into this issue with **ffmpeg version 4.2.2**. More information can be found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3831

Answer (score 0):

@matt that filter was downsampling the input because of `iw/2` and `ih/2`.
Which means divide input scales into 2 for the filter output, then upsampled again using `super2xsai` which means multiply the output scales into 2. But yes it indeed removes the warning of colorspace conversion at the expense of downgraded quality.

I was trying all available `hwaccels` on my device and the speed was faster because of hardware encoding. The colorspace conversion will be handled by your software and the encoding will be on hardware.